# Error "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am suffering the same "Cannot add foreign key constraint" that other folks around here.

The table **client_partners** contains a relationship between **users**. The error is raised at creating client_partners.

I have checked that **users.id** have the same type than **client_partners.clientid** and **client_partners.partnerid**: *INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL*.

The configuration options are:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

Users table definition:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `salt` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `role` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'supplier',
  `destination` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `supplierId` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_users_suppliers_idx` (`supplierId` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_users_roles_idx` (`role` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_users_destinations1_idx` (`destination` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_suppliers`
    FOREIGN KEY (`supplierId`)
    REFERENCES `suppliers` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_roles`
    FOREIGN KEY (`role`)
    REFERENCES `roles` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_destinations1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`destination`)
    REFERENCES `destinations` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Client_partners table definition:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `client_partners`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `client_partners` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client_partners` (
  `clientid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `partnerid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`clientid`, `partnerid`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_client_partners_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`clientid` , `partnerid`)
    REFERENCES `users` (`id` , `id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The datatypes (except autoincrement) are the same. The referencing table (users) is created first. What am I missing?

Comment: Its still not clear from your question;which table fails?

Comment: Error is raised when creating the table client_partners. Thanks for pointing it, I edited the question too.

Comment: You cant have the same column in a composite foreign key,maybe you want 2 foreign keys for each column  `CONSTRAINT `fk_client_partners_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`clientid` )
    REFERENCES `users` (`id`)` same for partnerid just change the constraint name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_client_partners_1`    
FOREIGN KEY (`clientid` , `partnerid`)
REFERENCES `users` (`id` , `id`)
```

here you are referencing to `id` of table `users` twice..it is not possible. try by removing one and create

If you want to reference to another foreign key you need to create it by using another name.

Comment: Thanks, Sachu. As you a Mihai said, this is not the way to do it: I had to create another constraint for the second key.